# Search an element's content, excluding content of any children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some difficulty figuring this one out. I am trying to search through my list of items and find a number (current day). Then add a `css` class to that list item.

This is working, but with a slight glitch: I want to be able to exclude all the text that exists inside the `<p></p>` tags. (Not quite sure how to do this). After some reading, I think I should be using the `.not` feature, but I think I might be doing it incorrectly.

Here is the jQuery I am currently using:

```
$("li:contains('" + thisDay + "')").not("p").addClass("current");
```

For your convenience, I have created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w5uk6/) which displays my problem to you.

You will notice that every List Item with the number "19" in it is highlighted.

Could you tell me how to modify only the `li` that contains `19` and does not search the  `<p></p>` tags for `19` as well?

Comment: You only want to change color of date text not the content am I right?

Comment: @YogeshSharma I think he wants to change the color of the whole thing, but **only** for elements that have the *header number* 19. His problem is that the code currently changes color if it has 19 *anywhere* in the content, rather than **only** if 19 is in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. You could wrap the day in a `span` and target that instead, or you could filter out the text nodes and check them:

http://jsfiddle.net/EfKJ4/

```
$('.cal').filter(function () {    
    return $(this).contents()[0].textContent == thisDay;
}).addClass('current');
```

- `filter()` lets you specify a function to run so you can have more control over the filtering (`:contains()` only does a wildcard search)
- `contents()` returns all children, including text nodes, which is what your "day" numbers are.
- `[0]` returns the first child, which in this case is the day number. You may want some error checking/handling here to make the solution more robust.
- If you return `true` from the filter callback, the item will be included in the result. Return `false`, and it won't. So we want to return true when the text content is equal to the day you're looking for.

Comment: AWESOME... This is exactly what I was after, Thanks so much. Not 100% sure what it does, but i'll read up on it. :)

Comment: @Mike I added a few notes, hopefully that will help.

Comment: This is great! Thanks again Jason!! Makes sense to me now. :D

Answer (score 0):

`color` property is inherited to the child elements, you can prevent this by simply add the following to your css:

```
li p{
 color:initial;
}
```

*(You can use a more specific selector.)*

**To downvoters :**

> This is working, but with a slight glitch: I want to be able to exclude all the text that exists inside the `<p></p>` tags
>
> Could you tell me how to modify only the li that contains 19 and does not search the  `<p></p>` tags for 19 as well?

OP doesn't want the `<p>` tags to be affected by the css in `.current` c;ass. my solution does just that. comments are welcome

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/w5uk6/1/)

Comment: In your Fiddle it still highlights (for example) the number 17 (!= 19) green. Something the OP doesn't want.

Comment: @ZiNNED it's happening in the original fiddle as well, it's not related to the requirement, from what i understand, op don't want the  `<p>` tags to be affected by the `.current` class which changes the color..

Comment: You are right the OP isn't specific about it and that it's up for debate. I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: Ill undo whoever wasnt removing the last downvote! :) Sorry if my question wasn't clear. But I meant I want my Jquery to search the list item ONLY and exclude `<p></p>` tags from the search. CSS can be applied to all text in the list item. But to ONLY the one with 19 as the date. Thank you for your answer though!